# Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives

Tags: android, gradle

when i run project..or clean and rebuild the project i got 4 error like

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives:  Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives: Caused by:
>   com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed t
>   Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program
>   type already present: com.bumptech.glide.Glide
>   **i copied also multiDexEnabled true in  defaultConfig tag.**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
/*implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.60"*/
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'net.rimoto:intlphoneinput:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.3'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'


// retrofit, gson
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
// Volley
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.6'


// fire base core
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.irozon.mural:mural:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.zetbaitsu:Compressor:31d924ea86'
// FCM messaging
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'


implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.yarolegovich:mp:1.0.9'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

please suggest me if anyone have got same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok this one is quite tricky so i can't put a finger on the issue, but what i did was i migrate to android x and then added this into the implementation

`('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'){ 
exclude group: "com.android.support"
}`

see if it runs, also i have added

`annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0`.

I'm not saying these will work but it's really worth a try because honestly, i messed up my versions in my gradle.app too lol and also it took me days to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much..you save my day..its working now

Comment: was searching for an answer like a mad man too, hahaha glad i could help!